# Best way to import data to macro enabled excel file

Tags: php, excel, csv, phpexcel, vba

I've already done a lot of the leg work here and I've assumed that I was going to do it this one way, but I'm not sure that it will work now. I have created an inventory system for my business using excel and it has a number of Macros (VBA scripts) - let's call it Inventory Master. I'm trying to keep track of all of my inventory across all of the different selling mediums (Amazon, eBay, personal store).

I've created a PHP script to pull sales data from Amazon and convert the XML date (request data from Amazon) into two separate csv files - for those who care, the way Amazon's API works, I have to make one request to pull of Sales Order IDs for that day and then another request using the Sales Order ID to get the actual order information.

THE PROBLEM is that I'm not sure what the best way to import the data that I need from the two files, into my inventory master. Also, I have to be able to filter the data that I want to import and place it into the appropriate columns in the Inventory Master.

I was going to create an VBA script to import the files, but I'm sure if I can manipulate the data this way, since the import data is a csv and doesn't have macros enabled. I'm sure I could still find a way, but I was then thinking that I might just be able to do all of this via PHP, but the only PHPExcel library I see doesn't work in xlsm formats.

This is where I turn to the internet. Can anyone think of a better way to import this data?

Comment: Excel has standard functionality to open csv files. You cannot add a VBA macro to a csv file, but you can open a csv file in Excel from a VBA script. It seems like you already know this, so what exactly are you missing?

Comment: I'm not exaclty clear on what you need to do. Is it correct that you need to import a csv to your macro enabled excelfile? That is easily done with a macro on the excelfile.

Comment: @Wiebe You can actually run a vba script on a csv file. All you need to do is create a add-in macro that runs each time you run Excel, then in the code you just look at the filename and extension if .csv -> continue code else exit the code.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I mentioned it. I can't import all of the data in the csv file. Unfortunately, I have to pick and choose what data I import and I have to be able to place it where I want in Inventory Master.

Comment: Why can't you import all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to do it in stages. Any database manipulation usually goes through a staging table. A temporary table which you manipulate before copying it to the final table.

Andreas suggested you import the entire file into excel. Run your filters through the file in excel before copying it to the Inventory Master.

You can then dispose of the temporary file.